# Page isn't taking masterpage design

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, master-pages

The problem that i'm having is that i made a master page like i always do. Then i add a views folder and add a web form using master page. But the design from the master page isn't showing on newly made web form.

`<%@ Page Title="Home - " Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/App_Themes/Theme/shop.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="home.aspx.cs" Inherits="Shop.Views.home" %>`

Comment: Webforms or MVC ? I am confused ?

Comment: It's hard to tell without more information. Did you add the master attribute to your page declaration? eg. `<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/Master1.master" Title="Content Page"%>`

Comment: @ashes999 , i did , but it aint working. And its Webforms not MVC

Comment: @NicolasPierre, then perhaps you should remove the asp.net-mvc tag from your question. It's bad enough that you didn't provide the slightest amount of code. Guessing your platform is double difficult when you mistag.

Comment: I added my webforms code

Comment: It's some time ago I did themes on ASP, but from this code I'd think you just set the wrong theme for your form. Make sure you have the right theme set first, different themes have different masterpages.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check "set masterpage" when you are adding a new webform in visual studio.

Comment: @NicolasPierre you'd be surprised how often people solve their questions by missing something obvious.

Comment: @NicolasPierre good, but ashes999 is right. I wasn't implying you were stupid, but you didn't really give much information in your question. A lot of these kind of questions like "help something is not working i don't know why" are solved by answers like mine...

Comment: Yeah i know but i'm not a newbie so :p Dunno why the masterpage isnt selected